# How do I display form instance values outside of input forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)


class Patron(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)
    checked_out_to = models.ForeignKey(Patron, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class BookInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

Consider the code snippet above.  I'm trying to create a form that displays the provided information from the given model instance, but only allows for the `checked_out_to` field to be editted.  The other fields *should not display as input fields.*

The readonly, hidden, and disabled attributes are not what I'm looking for.

Thank you for reading my question :)

EDIT:  I will be looking to expand this into a formset as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
class BookInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Allows 'instance' to be callable from template
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__
```

In the template:

```
{{ form.instance.author.name }} - {{ form.instance.title }}
```